# Highcharts Highmaps prevent initial zoom effect

Tags: animation, highcharts, zooming

I built a map with Highmaps that initially zooms in to a lat lon position: [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/mhw89pn2/1/)

Here is my code:

```
    parsed: function() {
  var chart = this.chart,
    center = chart.fromLatLonToPoint({
      lat: 50,
      lon: 10
    });

   setTimeout(function() {
     chart.mapZoom(.2, center.x, center.y);
```

When the map is loaded and when the time slider is started the map zooms in. How can I prevent this animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable animation on the chart level and restore it after initial zoom:

```
chart: {
  animation: false,
  ...
}
```

---

```
chart.update({
  chart: {
    animation: true
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xarg940y/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.animation

Comment: Thank you, @ppotaczek. When I start the slider the zoom effect disappears. But the inital zooming on load is still there. Is there a way to avoid this, too?

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, The initial zoom is caused by the `setTimeout` function. You can move the zoom to `load` event. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gk927uth/

Comment: that is the result I wanted. Thank you again!